# magento delete my account

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

Can i delete a customer from frontend in magento. I want to give access to the user "delete my account".

And in the controller placed the action.

```
public function deleteAccountAction()
{
    $log_customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();       
    $log_customer->delete();
    $this->_getSession()->logout()
        ->setBeforeAuthUrl(Mage::getUrl());
    $this->_redirect('*/*/');
}
```

But this throws exception like

> a:5:{i:0;s:51:"Cannot complete this
>   operation from non-admin
>   area.";i:1;s:1348:"#0
>   /home/makegood/public_html/stage/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(505):
>   Mage::throwException('Cannot
>   complete...')

How to solve this issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of deleting you could `setIsActive(false)` which would stop the user from logging in.
The account would still show in the admin but be deactivated.

Comment: I agree with setting to not-active.  You may run into some difficulties with viewing orders placed by said customer.

Comment: More than that, destroying customer data is just generally a painful idea. Third for isActive.

Answer (score 6):

You have to set `Mage::register('isSecureArea', true);` before deleting the customer from frontend